# React Fuzzy Search with Datalists - Values with Whitespace and Editing Input

Tags: reactjs, html-input, html-datalist

I have created a `fuzzy search` react component. The intent is to be able to enter a dataset name into an `input` and a `datalist` is populated with suggestions of close matches to the current value. The basic design has been implemented and works fine.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/38yxk6wqq1

**I am facing two issues:**

1 ) Datalist not recognizing `whitespace`. If the search strings are separated with `whitespace` the `datalist` does not populate. To account for this, I am replacing the `whitespace` characters with `_`. **Id rather not have to replace characters**, as the results from `fuse.js` are valid and accurate. Its the `datalist` tag that doesnt seem to like what I am doing.

2) `Datalist` not populating when editing middle of a string. Say a user enters a search string for example `freki_talis_lagg_test_05`, the `datalist` appropriately searches and populates correctly. If the user then edits the input string to `freki_talis__test_05`, and then edits it again from the middle of the string to `freki_talis_lagg_test_05` the `datalist` does not render even though the `fuse.js` has returned the appropriate results and my async call to my database works.

It is a bit hard to articulate in text so I created a short gif below:

[image: Editing middle of input]

```
import React from 'react';
import Fuse from 'fuse.js';
import _ from 'lodash';


class DatasetSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datasets: [{"name":"freki_recorder_test_20180404_093731"},{"name":"freki_talis_lagg_test_05"},{"name":"freki_talis_lagg_test_03"},{"name":"freki_talis_lagg_test_02"},{"name":"freki_recorder_test_20180403_irb_force_2"}],
      name: this.props.datasetName,
      results: [],
      options: {
        shouldSort: true,
        threshold: 0.6,
        location: 0,
        distance: 100,
        maxPatternLength: 32,
        minMatchCharLength: 1,
        keys: [
          "name",
        ]
      },
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFuzzySearch = this.handleFuzzySearch.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const { handleUpdateConfig } = this.props;
    const value = _.replace(e.target.value, ' ', '_');
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({
      name: value
    }, () => {
      this.handleFuzzySearch(this.state.name);
    })
  }

  handleFuzzySearch(value) {
    const { datasets } = this.props;
    const { options } = this.state;
    const fuse = new Fuse(this.state.datasets, options);
    const results = fuse.search(value).slice(0,5);
    this.setState({
      results: results
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { results } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={{width: '100%'}}>
        <input type='search' list='datasets' onChange={this.handleChange} style={{width: '100%'}} value={this.state.name}/>
        <datalist id='datasets'>
          { results.map((dataset) => <option key={dataset.id} value={dataset.name} />) }
        </datalist>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your question?